# Gulp-sass breaks when changes are made to imported file

Tags: css, sass, gulp-sass

- I am using `gulp-sass` to compile sass. I have `main.scss` and 
  `grid.scss` in the same directory.
- `main.scss` is watched by gulp watch.
- `grid.scss` is imported to `main.scss` and compiles without errors when `main.scss` is saved.

The problem is when **I make changes to `grid.scss` and save** gulp-sass breaks and throws this error:

```
    events.js:141
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ^
     Error: src\styles\main.scss
     Error: File to import not found or unreadable: grid
     Parent style sheet: stdin
     on line 1 of stdin
     >> @import "grid";
     ^

    at options.error (C:\www\test\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:277:32)
```

It looks like `grid.scss` is seen as non-existing file while it's being saved. What are the solutions ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `underline` before the file name to ignore the compilation for the file itself.

It should look like:

```
main.scss
_grid.scss
```

then your file `_grid.scss` you only compile into main.scss and not compile itself.

Also, make sure you have file permissions on the file/folder. Could be locking the compiler.

Comment: Still the same thing, imported file being a partial is not the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried watching the entire folder? it seems like you could be watching only the main file.

Comment: It is enough just to watch `main.scss` since others are imported in it.